# How to start data node(s) and compute node(s) without accessing the DolphinDB web interface?

Tags: dolphindb, datanode

I have executed `sh startController.sh` and `sh startAgent.sh` to start the controller(s) and agent(s). But I cannot start data node(s) and compute node(s) via the web interface, because the server port is not open.

Does anyone have best practices about how to do this? Thanks for any help or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start data nodes and compute nodes, you can:

(1) configure the parameter *datanodeRestartInterval* in *controller.cfg*.

For detailed instructions, please refer to the [Cluster Mode — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation](https://www.dolphindb.com/help200/DatabaseandDistributedComputing/Configuration/ClusterMode.html?highlight=datanoderestartinterval).

(2) connect to the controller you started and then use the `startDataNode` function.

(3) execute a script like the following one:

```
./dolphindb -home /data/ddb/server/clusterDemo/data/P1-node1 -logFile /data/ddb/server/clusterDemo/log/P1-node1.log -jobLogFile /data/ddb/server/clusterDemo/log/P1-node1_job.log -keyPath /data/ddb/server/clusterDemo/data/agent1/keys -publicName 127.0.0.1 -console 0 -mode datanode -localSite 10.5.0.4:8975:P1-node1 -webLoginRequired 0 -perfMonitoring 1 -sites 10.5.0.7:8979:P3-node1,10.5.0.6:8977:P2-node1,10.5.0.4:8975:P1-node1,10.5.0.2:8972:controller2:controller,10.5.0.3:8973:controller3:controller,10.5.0.5:8971:controller1:controller -streamingHAMode raft -stdoutLog 0 -newValuePartitionPolicy add -config /noconfig -controllerSite 10.5.0.2:8972:controller2 -chunkCacheEngineMemSize 8 -maxConnections 512 -streamingRaftGroups 2:P1-node1:P2-node1:P3-node1 -maxMemSize 8 -dfsReplicationFactor 2 -remoteExecutors 2 -workerNum 8 -localExecutors 7 -dataSync 1 -maxPubConnections 64 -lanCluster 0 -subExecutors 2 -enableHTTPS 0 -subPort 8001
```